# primefaces PieChartModel's Data

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am new to primefaces.
when I'm generating the PieChart i.e. setting PieChartModel with static or sample information, it works fine, but when I use the data from the database, it gives me java.lang.NullPointerException

my bean

```
public class ChartControllerPie {
    @EJB
    private session.SubscribeFacade ejbsubscribe;

    public List<String> v() {
        return ejbsubscribe.allVille();
    }
    private PieChartModel pieModel;

    public ChartControllerPie() {
        createPieModel();
    }

    public PieChartModel getPieModel() {
        return pieModel;
    }

    private void createPieModel() {
        pieModel = new PieChartModel();

        pieModel.set("bouhajla", 1540);
        pieModel.set("meknasi", 325);
        pieModel.set("mater", 702);
        pieModel.set("najta", 421);
    }
}
```

this method return a result

```
   @EJB
    private session.SubscribeFacade ejbsubscribe;

    public List<String> v() {
        return ejbsubscribe.allVille();
    }
```

but when i add this  v();  ????? not work 
my bean

```
    public class ChartControllerPie {
    @EJB
    private session.SubscribeFacade ejbsubscribe;

    public List<String> v() {
        return ejbsubscribe.allVille();
    }
    private PieChartModel pieModel;

    public ChartControllerPie() {
        createPieModel();
    }

    public PieChartModel getPieModel() {
        return pieModel;
    }

    private void createPieModel() {
        pieModel = new PieChartModel();
        v();// for use data
        pieModel.set("bouhajla", 1540);
        pieModel.set("meknasi", 325);
        pieModel.set("mater", 702);
        pieModel.set("najta", 421);
    }
}
```

is simply the problem is create PieChartModel from database

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:composition template="statistiquefaces.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="title">
        </ui:define>


        <ui:define name="centre">
    <p:pieChart id="custom" value="#{chartControllerPie.pieModel}" legendPosition="e" fill="false" showDataLabels="true"
                            title="Custom Options" style="width:400px;height:300px" sliceMargin="5" diameter="150" /> 

     </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </html>
```

Comment: post your xhtml code.

Comment: I think you should check the line where exactly it's giving error, and after viewing your issue it seems like it is having some issue with fetching data using ejb. so please try to fetch data successfully in any sample bean without using pie chart to solve the confusion.

Comment: sorry for the delay, this method works well in another method, but createPieModel () {} does not work,
My friend uses the same method but the import data from web service, it works well, is there an annotation for foce of taking the data?